# Isomorphism between set of all R-modules homomorphisms

Tags: modules, principal-ideal-domains

Let $S$ be an $R$-module where $R$ is an integral domain and let $P = \langle p \rangle $ be a prime ideal.

Define:

$S_{P}=\{s \in S: p^{n} s=0 \ \textrm{for some natural }n\}$.

As usual, denote $\mathrm{Hom}_{R}(S,S)$ the set of all homomorphisms (of $R$-modules) from $S$ to $S$.

Let $S$ be a torsion $R$-module where $R$ is a domain. Can someone please explain why is the following isomorphism true?

$$\mathrm{Hom}_{R}(S,S) \cong \prod_{P\text{ prime}} \mathrm{Hom}_{R}(S_{P},S_{P})$$

Comment: The product over *what*? Are you taking the product over all prime ideals $P$?

Comment: @Arturo Magidin: yes, I'm sorry.

Comment: @new: *All* prime ideals? How do you define $S_P$ when $P$ is not principal? (you are only assuming $R$ is a domain, so you don't know whether primes are principal or not).

Comment: Just a question what you mean by '$P=\langle p \rangle$ a prime ideal' : are you only considering the principal prime ideals? Also, $\lbrace 0\rbrace$ is such an ideal, do you consider it too? If not, what do you make of the case where $R$ is a field?

Comment: @new: You still don't say what to do with nonprincipal ideals. Since you are quoting it from a book, please (i) quote it **correctly**; and (ii) give the source in the body of the post.

Comment: @new: Since Section 9.1 in Rotman's book is called "Modules over PIDs", I think it is fairly clear that this is supposed to be a PID, not an arbitrary domain. Also, the definition of $p$-primary **explicitly** excludes the $0$-ideal, something you did not exclude in your definition.

Answer (score 4):

As stated the assertion is incorrect. (See below)

Take $R=\mathbb{Z}$, $S=\mathbb{Z}/6\mathbb{Z}$ (a torsion module).

Note that for a rational prime $p$ and $x\in S$, $p^nx = 0$ if and only if $6|p^nx$. In particular, we must either have $x=0$, or $x=3$ and $p=2$; or $x=2$ or $x=4$ and $p=3$. So we have:
$$S_P = \left\{\begin{array}{ll}
S & \text{if }P=\langle 0\rangle;\\
\{0,3\} &\text{if }P=\langle 2\rangle;\\
\{0,2,4\} & \text{if }P=\langle 3\rangle;\\
\{0\} &\text{otherwise.}
\end{array}\right.$$

Now, $\mathrm{Hom}_R(S,S)$ has six elements (one each for the possible images of the generator of $S$). And
$$|\mathrm{Hom}_R(S_P,S_P)| = \left\{\begin{array}{ll}
6 & \text{if }P=\langle 0\rangle;\\
2 &\text{if }P=\langle 2\rangle;\\
3 &\text{if }P=\langle 3\rangle;\\
1 &\text{otherwise.}
\end{array}\right.$$

So
$$\left|\prod_{P\text{ prime}}\mathrm{Hom}_R(S_P,S_P)\right| = 6\times 2 \times 3 = 36\neq 6 = \left|\mathrm{Hom}_R(S,S)\right|,$$
and I still don't see how they can be isomorphic, even if $S$ is torsion and $R$ is a PID.

---

The OP notes he's taken it from Rotman's book. The problem is from the section on modules over PIDs, so it is clear that $R$ is meant to be a PID, not merely a domain. In addition, the problem takes the product over all $P$-primary components of $S$, and the definition of $P$-primary **explicitly** excludes the zero prime. So, what we really have is:

> Let $R$ be a PID. Let $S$ be a torsion $R$-module, and for each nonzero prime $P=(p)$ of $R$, let $S_P$ be the $P$-primary component of $S$,
>   $$S_P = \{x\in S\mid p^nx=0\text{ for some }n\in\mathbb{N}\}.$$
>   Then 
>   $$\mathrm{Hom}_R(S,S) = \prod_{P\text{ nonzero prime}} \mathrm{Hom}_R(S_P,S_P).$$

To see this, simply use the fact that since $S$ is torsion, then $S$ is the sum of its $P$-primary components,
$$S = \bigoplus_{P\text{ nonzero prime}} S_P.$$Take $R=\mathbb{Z}$, $S=\mathbb{Z}/4\mathbb{Z}$. Then $\mathrm{Hom}_R(S,S)$ has four elements. If $P=(0)$, then $S_P = S$; if $P=(2)$, then $S_P=\{0,2\}$. If $P$ is neither of these, then $S_P=\{0\}$. $\mathrm{Hom}_R(S_2,S_2)$ has two elements. So the product on the right has $8$ elements in it, while $\mathrm{Hom}_R(S,S)$ has $4$, so the two cannot be isomorphic. So in fact, any module homomorphism from $S_P$ to $S$ will have image in $S_P$.

A map form a direct sum $\oplus M_i$ to a module $M$ is equivalent to a family of maps $f_i\colon M_i\to M$.

To see this, simply use the universal property of the direct sum: if $\iota_j\colon M_j\to \oplus M_i$ is the canonical embedding of $M_j$ into the direct sum, then for any family of homomorphisms $\f_j\colon M_j\to M$ there exists a unique homomorphism $f\colon \oplus M_i\to M$ such that $f_j = f\circ \iota_j$; this shows that for every element of $\prod\mathrm{Hom}_R(M_j,M)$ there is a unique corresponding element of $\mathrm{Hom}_R(\oplus M_i,M)$. Conversely, given any $f\colon\oplus M_i\to M$, we obtain a family of maps $f_j\colon M_j\to M$ by letting $f_j = f\circ\iota_j$ (equivalently, thinking of $M_j$ as a submodule of $\oplus M_i$, then $f_j$ is simply the restriction of $f$ to $M_j$). This defines a map $\mathrm{Hom}_R(\oplus M_i,M)$ to $\prod\mathrm{Hom}_R(M_j,M)$. It is now easy to see that the uniqueness clause of the universal property ensures that the two constructions are inverses of each other, proving the isomorphism. (This isomorphism is in fact *categorical*: for any category $\mathcal{C}$, if $A_i$ are objects and $\coprod A_i$ is their coproduct, then the elements of $\mathcal{C}(\coprod A_i,B)$ corresponds to families $\{f_i\}_{i\in I}$ with $f_i\in\mathcal{C}(A_i,B)$).

So
$$\begin{align*}
\mathrm{Hom}_R(S,S) &= \mathrm{Hom}_R(\oplus S_P, S)\\
&\cong \prod \mathrm{Hom}_R(S_P, S)\\
&=\prod\mathrm{Hom}_R(S_P,S_P),
\end{align*}$$
since, as discussed, any map from $S_P$ to $S$ actually has image in $S_P$.

Comment: sorry! I'm very sorry, I forgot to state that $S$ is a torsion $R$-module, this appears in Rotman's book (Advanced Modern algebra) page 663, ex 9.5

Comment: although I'm not sure if $R$ being a domain suffices. Don't we need the fact that $R$ is a PID so that $M$ is the direct sum of $S_{P}$ where $P$ rans over all prime ideals $P$ to show it is surjective/injective?

Comment: thanks, asuming I don't know the fact that $Hom_{R}(\oplus S_{p},S) \cong \prod Hom_{R}(S_{P},S)$ can we construct the map as you did previously, taking the restrictions?

Comment: @new: I'll add the isomorphism to the body.